# how to show a dialog in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have a toolbar in jquery mobile, made up of a bunch of links, which load "pop" modal dialog boxes on top of my javascript application.

Like this:

Info

Where the div with id="about" has a data-role="page".  I'd like to open the same dialog from the code, perhaps as part of a button handler, but I can't find any way to do this.

This code does not work.  It only shows the elements of the "about" page transparently ontop of my currect page (without styling).  How do I do this?

```
$("#buttAbout").click(function () {
    $('#about').show();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like jQuery mobile's dialogs are quite different to jQuery UI. This should do what you want:

`$.mobile.changePage('#about','pop',false,true)`

The documentation for changePage is [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html). Basically, the first argument is the string to find the page you want (can be an element id, jQuery object, or a page URL), second argument is the page transition, third is the direction of the transition (false for forwards, true for backwards), and the final argument is whether you want the page URL to update after the transition. I think you'll also need to make sure that the `data-role` attribute is correctly set to `dialog` on the div for your dialog, in order to ensure the correct history/styling behaviour.

Comment: When I try this I get the javascript console message:  Uncaught cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'.

Comment: Have you initialised the dialog first? Under standard jQuery, you'd need to initialise the dialog with this:

`$("#about").dialog()`

or this:

`$("#about").dialog({ autoOpen: false })`

before you can call open. (The `autoOpen: false` version tells jQuery not to open the dialog when you first initialise it - which is probably the behaviour you want). I'd put this code inside a `$(function() {....})` block so it runs on page load. Once you've done that, code elsewhere should be able to call open and close whenever you like.

If this doesn't help, I'll have a play with jQuery mobile tonight :)

Comment: For some reason this does not work with jquery mobile.  My code example is too large for this comment, but if I include the querymobile include it does not work. With jquery-ui.js included instead it works.

Comment: Think I've found you a solution - I've edited my answer above. Hope that helps!

Comment: Tim,  The changepage does work, however, the buttons in my dialog do not trigger the button callback, and the dialog looks a bit different. When I load the dialog through an <a href... the unused part of the page is black, calling changepage directly leaves it grey.  That is okay, but I need to find out how to get my callbacks to work.  Thanks

Comment: Changing my data-role from "page" to "dialog" fixed my last problem.  thanks,

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted - happy to fix it if someone can explain :)